# React Bootstrap Card Won't Show

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to get this card and card deck to show up. Here is my App and Recipe component. I have both react bootstrap and react installed as well. I receive no errors in the console nor my linter. I have tried putting the Bootstrap in the JSX as well as a separate component.

Here is my JSX in my app that houses the Recipe component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './App.css';
import Recipe from './Components/Recipe'

const App = () => {
  const APP_ID = "fe56f905";
  const APP_KEY = "93ea7b34f667f1384d2a3dacf790cce9";
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([])
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('') 
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllRecipes()
  }, [query])

  const getAllRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`)
    const data = await response.json()
    setRecipes(data.hits)
    console.log(data.hits)
  }

  const searchUpdate = e => {
    setSearch(e.target.value)
    // console.log(search)
    setQuery('')
  }

  const getQuery = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setQuery(search)
  }
  return (
    <div className = "App">
    <form onSubmit={getQuery} className="search">
    <input className="search-bar" type="text" value={search} onChange={searchUpdate} />
    <button className="search-button" type="submit">
    Search
    </button>
    </form>
    {recipes.map(recipe=>(
      <Recipe
      key={recipe.recipe.label}
      name={recipe.recipe.label} 
      calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
      image={recipe.recipe.image}
      ingredients={recipe.recipe.ingredients}
      />
    ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

And here is my Component:

```
    import React from 'react'
import { Card, CardDeck } from 'react-bootstrap'

const Recipe = ({name,calories,image,ingredients}) => {
  return (
    <div>
<CardDeck>
  <Card>
    <Card.Img variant="top" src={image} />
    <Card.Body>
      <Card.Title>{name} Calories: {calories}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>
        {ingredients.map(ingredient => (
          <li>{ingredient.text}</li>
        ))}
      </Card.Text>
    </Card.Body>
    <Card.Footer>
      <small className="text-muted">Updated.</small>
    </Card.Footer>
  </Card>
  </CardDeck>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Recipe;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a return statement just before rendering  component

```
return <Recipe
      key={recipe.recipe.label}
      name={recipe.recipe.label} 
      calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
      image={recipe.recipe.image}
      ingredients={recipe.recipe.ingredients}
      />
```

Comment: I believe I have a return statement for both pieces of code. Where exactly do you mean?

Comment: Recreated your structure, problem might be caused by empty recipe array you're mapping. Try doing following

{recipes.map(recipe=>console.log(recipe))}

Comment: For some reason that console log isn't appearing. I edited the original question to show my full code.

Comment: Make sure you are actually keeping an array with length more thatn 0 in your recipes state.
You can achieve it by using React DevTools or console log.

Comment: What is supposed to be there instead of an empty array?

Comment: Your actual data that you want to display with your Cards : )
If there is no recipes to display, components won't be rendered